# Bitcoin Miner Storage Issue

Tags: miner-configuration, memory

I was installing a bitcoin miner on my surface pro 4 with 4 gb of RAM, and it took almost 14 hours before running out of space. I uninstalled bitcoin, but for some reason it's taking up like 100 gb of memory on my computer. It says it is in apps and data, but it won't show up anywhere! Please help. (I am also using windows 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the uninstall didn't remove your wallet or block files.

Delete the folder `C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin` to delete both of those.